# Linux mint firewall настройка

Tags: linux-mint, firewall

Здравствуёте.
Как настроить **firewall** для **Linux mint**? 
Какие есть для этого утилиты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант А:

терминально-настраиваемый IPTables - [тут](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-iptables-dlya-chajnikov) можно про него почитать
из минусов - все настройки (правила) IPTables введённые с консоли не сохраняются при следующем запуске системы, требуется править специальный скрипт

Вариант B:

UFW (Uncomplicated FireWall) и его графический интерфейс gUFW - вот [тут](http://osmaster.org.ua/kak-nastroit-faervol-v-linux/) можно посмотреть как его настраивать

Comment: Благодарю за ответ